# MYSQLI not playing nice with INSERT

Tags: mysql

So excuse the coding if it's not totally up to par, but I just got a hang of MYSQL and am switching to MYSQLI (procedural as I find it easier as I haven't learned object oriented yet, i'm new to this)
My problem is I have a simple 'Invoice' page on a small website that worked perfectly with MYSQL. When I switched to MYSQLI (I'm sure I am missing something obvious) I can echo all the variables, have checked for proper DB connection yet it will not INSERT anything into the DB.
This is the function in question, it is called after a "fill invoice" form is submitted, again, all the $_POST variables can be echoed in the function properly.

```
function createinvoice($billto,$cust,$addr,$desc,$desccost,$labcost,$comment){
$taxrate=".13";
$kaboom=str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n"),"<br />",$desccost); //keep original desccost for database
$kaboom=mysqli_real_escape_string(nl2br($kaboom));
$kaboom=nl2br($kaboom);
$lines=explode("<br />",$kaboom);
$matcost=0;

for($i=0;$i < count($lines);$i++) 
{
    $matcost=$matcost+$lines[$i];
}
$fullcost=$matcost+$labcost;
$taxdue = $fullcost*$taxrate;
$totaldue=$fullcost+$taxdue;

$desc=mysqli_real_escape_string($desc);
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO invoice(customerID,customerName,customerAddr,description,desccost,material,labour,taxdue,totaldue,comment)
VALUES('$billto','$cust','$addr','$desc','$desccost','$matcost','$labcost','$taxdue','$totaldue','$comment')");
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Edit: to show connection string

```
if(include("/../dbinvoice.php")){echo "DB file connected";}
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhostname, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){echo "No MYSQL connection: ".mysqli_connect_error();exit();}
```

Every time the page loads I get a message "DB file connected" showing it read the dbinvoice.php file and I don't get an error message with connect. I have verified with phpinfo() that mysqli is on my machine (webmatrix testing).

Comment: You should validate that the query was successful.  At the very least, check if `mysqli_query` returned `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  If `FALSE`, you'll get information about the error with [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/mysqli_error).

Comment: if I add a if(!mysqli....){echo "Some error: ".mysqli_error($con);} I get an output of Some error but nothing from the mysqli_error. I'm really beginning to wonder if I actually don't have a DB connection even though everything says I do. :(

Comment: A side note: what's up with `$kaboom`? You do what looks like a manual version of `nl2br`, then do `nl2br` the actual function twice, then use the resulting break tags for `explode`. You also appear to escape `$kaboom`, but then only use it to be exploded and used in math operations, while `$desccost` itself is interpolated into the query, but not escaped.

Comment: What do you mean by "everything says you do"?  Can you show the code where you establish the connection, and do you validate that the result of `mysqli_connect` also is `TRUE`?

Comment: Actually, now on-topic, where is `$con` coming from? It's not passed to the function or declared within it. Are you meaning to access it as a global variable?

Comment: I don't know why the $kaboom has a mysqli nl2br and then a nl2br - just a glitch on my behalf. I need the explode because I have to have each 'line' on a new line with a shaded background or unshaded. Yes, the $desccost slipped by me on the unescaped. Rectified.

Comment: Global variable as that's how I had it with MYSQL - open the connection and away I went. I call the DB from numerous functions perhaps that is not the case with mysqli and it needs individual calls?

Comment: MySQLi does not automatically grab the first open connection it finds as mysql_query() will do.  You must pass the resource in a variable `$con`, but that variable is not in scope in your function. You must pass it to the function, or use `global`, but passing it is much preferred.

Comment: Thank you. I tried passing it before and it didn't want to work. I wonder if it was just Firefox not loading the 'new' page and keeping the cached version. Works fine now. Thanks a bunch.